# Android show notification in the service method

Tags: android, notifications

and thanks to for read my problem.
i write simple application to show notification into the service who run the background:
i write this into the service class for show me simple notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =   new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.maleki) // notification icon
                        .setContentTitle("آذر گشت") // title for notification
                        .setContentText("شما"+" "+jsonArray.length()+" "+"خبر جدید دارید") // message for notification
                        .setAutoCancel(true); // clear notification after click
```

but not show me a notification,what happen?thanks.

My complete service class code is:

```
public class newsservice extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // your code
        new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://tour.maxitem.org/newslenght.aspx");
        //this.stopSelf();

        return Service.START_FLAG_REDELIVERY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    //************************************************************
    //***************************************AsyncTask

    private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            TourMyCountry country=new TourMyCountry();
            country.id="jamalnews";//.setName(etName.getText().toString());
            return POST(urls[0],country);
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(result);
                /*for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject JsonObj=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String countryname=JsonObj.getString("countryname");

                }*/

                /*NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =   new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.maleki) // notification icon
                        .setContentTitle("آذر گشت") // title for notification
                        .setContentText("شما"+" "+jsonArray.length()+" "+"خبر جدید دارید") // message for notification
                        .setAutoCancel(true); // clear notification after click*/

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }//END OF ASYNCTASK

    //**************************************POST LEVEL
    public static String POST(String url, TourMyCountry myCountry){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {
            // 1. create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            String json = "";
            // 3. build jsonObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.accumulate("id", myCountry.id);
            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = jsonObject.toString();
            // 5. set json to StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

            // 6. set httpPost Entity
            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            // 9. receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // 10. convert inputstream to string
            if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";
            Log.d("behzad in the service:",result);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        // 11. return result
        return result;
    }//END OF POST BACK TO RETURN

    //************************************************convertInputStreamToString
    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }
    //***************************************************************


    public class TourMyCountry{
        String id;
    }

}
```

Comment: The source you included isn't enough.  Share more, like the call you have to actually show the notification.  Include more code, or I suggest closing this with not enough info).

Comment: you havent called notify() method, where is it ?

Comment: @DavidJhons How can i call that?

Comment: Why do you have an AsyncTask in your Service class?!  This is already off the UI thread, so you don't need or want this.

Comment: @DavidJhons thanks for you,i solve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager)   getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// your code for notification builder
mNotifyMgr.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the method to actually set the notification.  It should look something like this:

```
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

Review this link, which describes how to send a notification: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Bottom line, your code is incomplete.